# Using key in chrome.storage.sync

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

Being new to JS and extensions this might be a rookie mistake.

I am using the sync storage API

```
var key = "chromeext_form_26" + tabid ;

chrome.storage.sync.set({ String(key),  tab1Obj }, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.error) {
        console.log("Runtime error.in setting");
    }
});
```

But this throws error as it does not recognize the key as string.I did try directly using "chromeext_form_26" + tabid as key it maps the object to "key" it self.

On typing `chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function (data) { console.info(data) });`
I can see the mapping as `Object { key: "efg"}`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make key dynamically, don't you?

After `var key` add the object keypair definition:

```
var pair={}; pair[key]=tab1Obj;
chrome.storage.sync.set(pair, function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware the first param of [StorageArea.set](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea) is an object, so you should Use `:` rather than `,`.

```
var key = "chromeext_form_26" + tabid ;

chrome.storage.sync.set({ String(key):  tab1Obj }, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.error) {
        console.log("Runtime error.in setting");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because chrome extensions are browser specific you can use ES6 features without having to worry about compatibility. ES6 adds computed property names which allow you to compute property names directly in the object declaration like this:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.set({ [key]: tab1Obj }, function() {
    // ...
});
```